# React SPA / Embedded Identity Server issue after .net core 3 preview 8 upgrade

Tags: c#, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We have a React SPA which was initially created using the SPA templates and running on .NET Core 3 preview 7. The React SPA "The client" was configured for implicit flow and successfully using the oidc-client. All working.

Here is the client config in my startup.cs:

```
        var mySPAClient = new IdentityServer4.Models.Client()
        {
            AccessTokenLifetime = accessTokenLifetime,
            RedirectUris =
                {
                    $"{host}/authentication/login-callback",
                    $"{host}/silent-refresh.html"
                },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                {
                    $"{host}/authentication/logout-callback"
                },
            ClientId = "projectName.web",
            AllowedScopes =
                {
                    "projectName.webAPI",
                    "openid",
                    "profile"
                },
            ClientName = "projectName.web",
            RequireConsent = false,
            AllowedGrantTypes =
                {
                    IdentityModel.OidcConstants.GrantTypes.Implicit
                },
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
        };
```

But now when i upgrade to preview 8 for any assembly that was preview 7 I am getting the following error in the logs

> *[10:55:34 Error] **Invalid grant type for client: "authorization_code"**
>   AuthorizeRequestValidationLog { ClientId: "projectName.web", ClientName: "projectName.web", RedirectUri: "https://localhost:44343/authentication/login-callback", AllowedRedirectUris: ["https://localhost:44343/authentication/login-callback", "https://localhost:44343/silent-refresh.html"], SubjectId: "anonymous", ResponseType: "code", ResponseMode: "query", GrantType: "authorization_code", RequestedScopes: "", State: "a1e84334a8c94b7db599ddb9336447c8", UiLocales: null, Nonce: null, AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses: null, DisplayMode: null, PromptMode: null, MaxAge: null, LoginHint: null, SessionId: null, Raw: [("client_id": "projectName.web"), ("redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44343/authentication/login-callback"), ("response_type": "code"), ("scope": "projectName.webAPI openid profile"), ("state": "a1e84334a8c94b7db599ddb9336447c8"), ("code_challenge": "E8p1sg1Y0TdbhxccGB-_fbx7D6GnJXfCpcYu1IHZC_k"), ("code_challenge_method": "S256"), ("prompt": "none")] } (IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator)
>   [10:55:34 Error] Request validation failed (IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint)*

I don't know why it now is referring to authorization_code and this error is appearing?

Cheers for any assistance

Comment: Can we see your Token endpoint call?

Comment: I have the same problem. Looks like the token endpoint is called twice, and it failed the second time since the authorization code is supposed to be used only once. (There is a successful token endpoint call before this one, with a userinfo call in between). I am not sure what is causing the behavior. So far, I can tell that the login component is mounted twice, hence two LoginCallback actions in componentDidMount. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey interesting I’m away but will check it out when I get back in a week

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `response_type` to be `"token"` rather than `"code"` and you should be ok

Update:

Make sure you provide correct `authority, client_id, response_type, scope` settings

Comment: When I hit the endpoint https://localhost:44343/_configuration/projectName.web it returns

{
    "authority": "https://localhost:44343",
    "client_id": "projectName.web",
    "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44343/authentication/login-callback",
    "post_logout_redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44343/authentication/logout-callback",
    "response_type": "id_token token",
    "scope": "projectName.webAPI openid profile"
}

So this seems correctly set already. 

That is the response type is correct.

Comment: Pretty sure I have correct settings. It was all working in preview 7 as mentioned

Comment: I am using Implicit as opposed to Authorization code, somehow it's treating the client as Authorization code when it's clearly not defined as such.

Comment: Since I'm not able to help you so I will give you a vote up so someone else can help

Comment: Authorization code is now the recommended grant type for javascript applications. See the note for Implicit: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html.  I would try and get authorization code working by changing the client's configuration to use 'GrantTypes.Code' instead of 'IdentityModel.OidcConstants.GrantTypes.Implicit'

Comment: Cheers @Richard maybe preview 8 doesn't support implicit, or it's just broken. Yes I'm aware implicit has vulnerabilities.

Comment: How do you load the client? 
I have similar client in Config and in the Startup.cs: .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients()) but it just does not work. It keeps throwing that the `spa` client does not exist

Comment: @ M U

yourClient.Properties.Add(ApplicationProfilesPropertyNames.Profile, ApplicationProfiles.SPA);

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out mine. But not sure if it is applicable to yours.
The problem in my case is that I have a process flow that is somehow mismatched. When I tried to modify the React with Auth sample to use EF Core, the updateState call is not made in the `AuthorizeService.js/completeSignIn()`. The code seems to cause another call to token endpoint before it goes back to `SignIn()`, with no `updateState()` call to save the state. And it is failing the second one since the code expired after the first call.
I somehow found another source code from the React with Redux sample, which has the requisite `updateState()` call in the `completeSignIn()`. And other than the very different AuthorizeService.js file, the other authentication/authorization related code are the same between the React with Auth sample and the React with Redux sample.
This is the new completeSignIn code:

```js
    async completeSignIn(url) {
        await this.ensureUserManagerInitialized();
        try {
            const { state } = await this.userManager.readSigninResponseState(url, this.userManager.settings.stateStore);
            if (state.request_type === 'si:r' || !state.request_type) {
                let user = await this.userManager.signinRedirectCallback(url);
                this.updateState(user);
                return this.success(state.data.userState);
            }
            if (state.request_type === 'si:p') {
                await this.userManager.signinSilentCallback(url);
                return this.success(undefined);
            }
            if (state.request_type === 'si:s') {
              await this.userManager.signinSilentCallback(url);
              return this.success(undefined);
            }

            throw new Error(`Invalid login mode '${state.request_type}'.`);
        } catch (signInResponseError) {
            console.log('There was an error signing in', signInResponseError);
            return this.error('Sing in callback authentication error.');
        }
    }
```